# Seeding using Prisma in Next.js app with a Heroku Postgresql db Timed out fetching a new connection

Tags: node.js, next.js, prisma, heroku-postgres

I have tried several ways to seed my database with a js file that I have.

data.ts

```
    export const scheduleData: {
      homeTeam: number;
      awayTeam: number;
      homeTeamConf: number;
      awayTeamConf: number;
      scheduleDate: string;
      week: number;
      leagueId: string;
    }[] = [
      {
        homeTeam: 51,
        awayTeam: 210,
        homeTeamConf: 4,
        awayTeamConf: 17,
        scheduleDate: "2022-12-10T20:00Z",
        week: 15,
        leagueId: "4",
      },
      {
        homeTeam: 335,
        awayTeam: 342,
        homeTeamConf: 27,
        awayTeamConf: 27,
        scheduleDate: "2022-10-12T23:30Z",
        week: 7,
        leagueId: "4",
      },
      //... and so on for hundreds of objects to be inserted in the db as rows
    ]
```

this is my seed.ts file and query that i am running:

```
    import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
    import { scheduleData } from "./scheduleData";
    
    const prisma = new PrismaClient();
    
    const seedSchedule = async () => {
      await Promise.all(
        scheduleData.map(async (game) => {
          return prisma.game.create({
            data: {
              homeTeam: {
                connect: { id: game.homeTeam },
              },
              awayTeam: {
                connect: { id: game.awayTeam },
              },
              scheduleDate: new Date(game.scheduleDate),
              league: {
                connect: { id: 4 },
              },
              week: game.week,
              conferences: {
                connect: [{ id: game.homeTeamConf }, { id: game.awayTeamConf }],
              },
            },
          });
        })
      );
    };
    
    seedSchedule()
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error(e);
        process.exit(1);
      })
      .finally(async () => {
        await prisma.$disconnect();
      });
```

This works for about the first 60 records and then i always get a message:

```
    Timed out fetching a new connection from the connection pool. More info: http://pris.ly/d/connection-pool (Current connection pool timeout: 10, connection limit: 17)
        at Object.request (./@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:45405:15)
        at async PrismaClient._request (./@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:46301:18)
        at async Promise.all (index 84) {
      code: 'P2024',
      clientVersion: '3.14.0',
      meta: { connection_limit: 17, timeout: 10 }
```

I've looked at multiple resources but i'm more front end oriented and struggling to figure out how to adjust the connection limit or other ways to get my seed to work.

Can someone help me get this seed to work?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the docs of prisma, every query (`create`/`delete`/`createMany` etc.) is performed on a separate connection (for your scenario, there are 17 available connections). When they are queued and some query takes longer than `timeout` seconds, all the queries in the queue will eventually timeout.

There are some useful [tricks in prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/performance-and-optimization/connection-management#optimizing-the-connection-pool) on how to optimize the connection pool so the queries. Especially for seeding, you could [disable the pool timeout](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/performance-and-optimization/connection-management#disabling-the-pool-timeout)
to allow prisma to process all queries in the queue without timing out.

However, I would highly suggest using `createMany` to create hundreds of records at once. But sometimes it's just not possible (like you're trying to connect the game record to multiple conference records at once).

Comment: thanks for the response Cedric! Are these options available on the hobby heroku postgres db level? i tried to write in those params in the db URL and the shadow URL (heroku needs 2 dbs for prisma) but it still timed out and didn't show an increase in the connection limit. But again i could be doing it wrong

Comment: also createMany doesn't work because i cant access relations with it.

Comment: If you're unable to adjust these parameters due to db limits (maybe it cannot accept more than x connections), you can obviously do some request chunking in your code and only start x queries at once.

However you should really take a look at the pool_timeout parameter which is only for the prisma engine and does not translate to a postgres feature.

Comment: where would i adjust that feature in the code? im not super back end oriented.

Comment: i just switched from heroku hosted postgres to my local postgres db and it worked fine. Thanks for helping!